# position fixed behave wired in iphone6（ios12.4.4）

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a group of buttons stick to bottom which i use `positon:fixed;bottom:0px` to ahchive. These buttons works perfectly in other iphones and androds, but they will shaking or（ be scrolled a little bit ） when i am scrolling the whole page.

here are relative code

```
//js Popup is a component with pop animation
        <Popup
            <div className="footer-fixed">
              <div className="confirm-button">
                ....
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </Popup>
```

```
//css
.footer-fixed {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
```